# ImportError: cannot import name '__check_build' while importing sklearn module (Python 3.4, Windows R2 2008 64-bit)

Tags: python-3.4

When I try to import sklearn module I get following error

```
ImportError: cannot import name '__check_build'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\sklearn_liveStream.py", line 14, in <module>
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\__init__.py", line 213, in <module>
    from .csr import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csr.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._sparsetools import csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks, \
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I did go through a similar question here:
[Scikit Learn and Count Vectorizer Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954833/scikit-learn-and-count-vectorizer-error)

But none of the solutions mentioned here seem to work for me.

Following are the steps taken by me so far

Re-install/upgrade to scipy using pip

Re-install scipy using whl file

Uninstalled sklearn module and installed it again using pip.

Re-installed sklearn using whl file

Following are the software versions I am using

OS : Windows R2, 2008

Python : 3.4.3 (64-bit)

Python Modules

-numpy (1.9.2)

-pip (7.0.1)

-scikit-learn (0.16.1)

-scipy (0.16.0b2)

Comment: Facing same problem, plz let me know if you were able to solve this.